# Swift 3, Xcode 8.2 dataTask request timeout

Tags: ios, swift3, timeout, xcode8.2

`dataTask(with: request)` method in **Swift 3** is working fine in office network but returning timeout in home network.

Not able to figure out what XCode configuration change is required to make it work in both environments.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

```
    func callWebService() {
    var config                              :URLSessionConfiguration!
    var urlSession                          :URLSession!

    config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // MARK:- HeaderField
    let HTTPHeaderField_ContentType         = "Content-Type"

    // MARK:- ContentType
    let ContentType_ApplicationJson         = "application/json"

    //MARK: HTTPMethod
    let HTTPMethod_Get                      = "GET"

    let callURL = URL.init(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/newapplications/limit=10/json")

    var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)

    request.timeoutInterval = 20.0 // TimeoutInterval in Second
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    request.addValue(ContentType_ApplicationJson, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField_ContentType)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod_Get

    let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        do {
            let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print("Result",resultJson!)
        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()

}
```

Comment: Test the request by using curl in terminal, if it doesn't connect even there then the issue is with your network/firewall.

Comment: @VIP-DEV I think author can even open the link in Safari to check that.

Comment: Yes you can try Larme's idea

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try out VIP-DEV's idea. By the way, I tried making the same request in XCode 7 using objective C and it worked fine in both environments. I face this issue only when I migrated to XCode 8.2 using swift. It works fine in safari in both environments.